# How can I create a EmailMessage Record in an EmailService?

Tags: apex, email, emailmessage

I've created an EmailService which I need to use to grab from the body the Record ID, create an EmailMessage record an relate it to the object.
Everything works fine, using some debug logs I've confirmed that there aren't any Exceptions, the EmailMessage records seem to be created but when I query: `SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage` there aren't any records.
This is how I'm creating it: [image: EmailService Creation]

Enhanced email is enabled. If I grab the ID from the inserted EmailMessage from a debug log I have after the insert, I receive this error:
[image]

Comment: any chance you have an async process that is deleting the EmailMessage before you query for it?

Comment: You are correct, there was another dev working in the org and he created a Flow that was deleting the EmailMessages. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to create an EmailMessage is correct.

Since you are taking the ID from the debug log and then pasting it into either the UX or an Apex script and then finding the EmailMessage doesn't exist, the likely culprit is:

- Some other automation either within the transaction or, as an async transaction, is deleting the EmailMessage. Async could be an async path on a Flow or future or queueable or maybe even a scheduled apex job

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me a lot!